# Creating oval in Swift with a Progress bar around it

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uibezierpath

I am trying to design something like this image where there is an oval, and then a progress bar around it. I've been able to draw a wacky oval with the border, but I am completely lost on the progress bar part of it, any help would be appreciated. Here is my code for the oval and what the output is

First image is what the code outputs, second image is the goal

```
 func setupOvalView(){
                
        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: self.ovalView.frame.origin.x, y: self.ovalView.frame.origin.y, width: self.ovalView.frame.width, height: self.ovalView.frame.height))
        
        
        let rect = CGRect(x: self.ovalView.frame.origin.x + 20, y: self.ovalView.frame.origin.y + 20, width: self.ovalView.frame.width - 40, height: self.ovalView.frame.height - 40)
        
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect)
        path.append(circlePath)
        path.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
        
        
        
        let fillLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        fillLayer.path = path.cgPath
        
        fillLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd
        fillLayer.fillColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        fillLayer.opacity = 0.5
        view.layer.addSublayer(fillLayer)
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unclear. Is the second picture the goal? Or what is the goal?

Comment: first is what the code outputs, second is the desired output

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can draw a part of an oval similar to the one from the picture you attached:

```
    let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 200))
    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    layer.path = path.cgPath
    layer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    layer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    layer.strokeStart = 0.5
    layer.strokeEnd = 0.8
    layer.lineWidth = 10
    layer.lineCap = .round
    view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
```

strokeStart and strokeEnd properties are used to set the start and end points of the progress line

Answer (score 1):

I got this pretty easily:

[image]

That seems to be much like what you're trying to draw. It's just three shape layers. You've already got one, so you'd add two more.

Comment: You used 3 CAShapeLayers to implement that?

Comment: For red and green layers - are you just adding stroke start/end?

Comment: Yes, that's the usual thing, especially if you want that nice rounding at the ends. :)

Comment: Appreciate it, I was having trouble rounding the corners with a different approach

Comment: Would you please post the code that gave you that output?

Comment: I'm specifically having an issue with adding the red/green layers on top of the gray. Also my line width is not changing